# Defining functions in Lua

Tags: function, lua

I read that we can declare a function in Lua with two different syntax:

```
function pr()
    print("I'm function pr()")
end

printt = function()
    print("I'm function printt()")
end

pr()
printt()
```

Though the functions seem to work exactly the same way when they're called I want to know if there's a difference between their implementation at lower level. Does the interpretor treats them exactly the same or do they differ in terms of speed, implementation, or in any way?

Comment: If you're in doubt about the generated code, looking at the output of `luac -l` may help.

Comment: In case you are transferring some understanding of the term "declare" from another language, you should know that in Lua you are creating a function definition which is an expression that when evaluated at runtime creates a function value. Your second syntax makes that more obvious. In your examples, not even the variables are "declared".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference between the two. The first one is just a syntactic sugar to the second form.

From the reference manual [Function Definitions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11):

> The syntax for function definition is
>
> ```
>   functiondef ::= function funcbody
>   funcbody ::= ‘(’ [parlist] ‘)’ block end
> ```
>
> The following syntactic sugar simplifies function definitions:
>
> ```
>   stat ::= function funcname funcbody
>   stat ::= local function Name funcbody
>   funcname ::= Name {‘.’ Name} [‘:’ Name]
> ```
>
> The statement
>
> ```
>   function f () body end
> ```
>
> translates to
>
> ```
>   f = function () body end
> ```